# Which is better: Adding the childs view as a subview to its parent or just straight up assigning its view to the parent?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Question is actually about the correct way of doing it. for example:

```
[self addChildViewController:self.childViewController];
[self.view addSubview:self.childViewController.view];

//Set its bounds accordingly
CGRect viewRect = self.view.bounds;
self.childViewController.view.frame = viewRect;
```

is this preferable or;

```
[self addChildViewController:self.childViewController];
self.view = self.childViewController.view;
```

is this fine too?

EDIT: Subview approach ended up better, expectedly. I don't know why the second one didn't cause any problems at first but it crashed later anyway, so, yeah... Thanks a bunch to all who answered.

Comment: Interesting read which will probably answer your question : [Creating Custom Container View Controllers](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not assign the container view controller's view. It is a container and may contain multiple child view controllers (see UITabBarController for example).

Instead you should add the child view controller's view as a subview to the container view controller's view.

Also make sure to call the appropriate methods in the child view controller (`-didMoveToParentViewController` and such).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think assigning `self.view` as `self.childViewController` is a good idea. Whenever later you'd like to add anything to `self.view` you'd in fact add it to `self.childViewController`. Your code will be mixed up. I'd go with first option.

If you want to exchange your entire `self.view`, then don't perform it in `childViewController` approach but just swap the view in `loadView` method and handle the view in this particular `UIViewController` instead of child.

Answer (score 0):

Assigning childViewController view to parent view is not a good practice. Assigning may lose the controls of childViewController and in such case your app may crash. So adding childViewController view as a subView to parent is good. 
i.e

```
[self addChildViewController:self.childViewController];
[self.view addSubview:self.childViewController.view];
```